# Firebase registered phone number(contacts) listing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, contacts

I need to list all registered phone number(users) from firebase. I have tried the below solution, but it didn't work fo me. Please help.

```
  DatabaseReference ref = 
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //Get map of users in datasnapshot
                    collectPhoneNumbers((Map<String,Object>) 
                    dataSnapshot.getValue());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    //handle databaseError
                }
            });
}
private void collectPhoneNumbers(Map<String,Object> users) {

    ArrayList<Long> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    //iterate through each user, ignoring their UID
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : users.entrySet()){

        //Get user map
        Map singleUser = (Map) entry.getValue();
        //Get phone field and append to list
        phoneNumbers.add((Long) singleUser.get("phone"));
    }

    System.out.println(phoneNumbers.toString());
}
```

Comment: please show the database

Comment: @PeterHaddad It was my mistake, in database no such node named 'users'. it was  user in db. Thank you